How to build an expiring function in Wordpress?
I need a Data Layer in my WordPress header.php. It's already running by author like this:
<?php $author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_queried_object_id()); if (get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id) === 'AUTHOR1') { echo '<script> var dataLayer = []; dataLayer.push({'author': 'ALIAS_AUTHOR_1'}); </script>'; } ?>

Now the tricky part: The data layer should disappear 30 days after publish date (not modified date). I really searched the whole web but I did not find any way to let a function stop by Date published plus X days. Any thoughts about that?

Note that injecting <script> tags this way is frowned upon in WordPress. It's better to use wp_enqueue_script() to add the script; you can use wp_localize_script() to pass data from PHP to the script if you need to.

In this code we are getting the Publish Date using get_the_date() to retrieve the publish date of the current post. and then calculating the difference by comparing the publish date with the current date.
After this we conditionally output the script. The condition is if the publish date is within the last 30 days, output the data layer script.
You  can achieve your desired results with the help of given code.
<?php
// This is to get the author ID of the current post.
$author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', get_queried_object_id() );

// This is to get the publish date of the current post.
$publish_date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', get_queried_object_id() );
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

// This is to calculate the difference in days between the publish date and the current date.
$date_diff = ( strtotime( $current_date ) - strtotime( $publish_date ) ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 );

if ( get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) === 'AUTHOR1' && $date_diff <= 30 ) {
    echo '<script> var dataLayer = []; dataLayer.push({"author": "ALIAS_AUTHOR_1"}); </script>';
}
?>


That one works like a charm. Thank you so much, Narendra!

You're welcome, if this answers your question could you mark it as the correct answer? It's the big tick under the voting buttons, it'd be a huge help :)
